# Dynamics CRM Web API Add Marketing List to Campaign ""Association cannot be performed between an entity of type campaign and an entity of type list.""

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I am getting the error, "Association cannot be performed between an entity of type campaign and an entity of type list." when I try to use Dynamics CRM Online Web API to make a connection between a Campaign and a Marketing List.

I am using V9.0 of the api

**Approach 1: deep insert**

POST: 
    {{webapiurl}}campaigns

Body:

```
 {
    "name": "test 2",

    "campaignlist_association": [

    {
        "listname":"test3", 
        "createdfromcode":2
    }

]

}
```

Response:
{

"error": {
        "code": "0x80040203",

"message": "Association cannot be performed between an entity of type campaign and an entity of type list.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "Association cannot be performed between an entity of type campaign and an entity of type list.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.Solution.Common.CrmNotSupportedException",
        }
    }
}

**Approach 2: Association** 
POST: 
    …/campaigns(000000000xxxxxx)/campaignlist_association/$ref

Body:

```
{  
"@odata.id":"{{webapiurl}}/lists(11111111xxxxxxxx)"  
}
```

Response:

{
"error": {
        "code": "0x80040203",

"message": "Association cannot be performed between an entity of type campaign and an entity of type list.",

"innererror": {
            "message": "Association cannot be performed between an entity of type campaign and an entity of type list.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.Solution.Common.CrmNotSupportedException",
       }
    }
}

**Results**
Both approaches yield the same error message: "Association cannot be performed between an entity of type campaign and an entity of type list."  However, when if I relate them in the Dynamics CRM UI, and query campaigns I accurately see the list assigned to the campaign if I expand the "campaignlist_association" property via the web api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many native N-N relationships require an action to be called instead of an association POST request to associate multiple records. You can check the available out of the box Web API actions list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/actions?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)

In your case in specific you need to call *Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddItemCampaign* action in a POST request like this:

URL:

```
[Organization URI]/lists(YourMarketingListGUID)/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddItemCampaign
```

Body:

```
{
    "Campaign": {
        "campaignid": "YourCampaignGUID"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try. I exported this from my postman. Replace {} with your values.

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://{YOUR_ORGANIZATION_URL_HERE}/api/data/v9.0/lists({MARKETING_LIST_UUID})/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddItemCampaign' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "Campaign": {
        "campaignid": "{CAMPAIGN_ID}",
        "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.campaign"
    }
}'
```

Here's an example:

[image]

You can see that in dynamics the data was created properly inside my campaign

[image]

[image]